# ionic: making ng if in a select depending on a radio button status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm making an template for an app, and i need to show a select component when one of the previous radio buttons is set in a determined state. The logic is this:

The current code I have got is this:

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="tipo">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Gato</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="g" checked></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Perro</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="p"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <div ng-if="tipo === 'g'">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Choose</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="raza1">
          <ion-option value="angora">angora</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="persa">persa </ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="tipo === 'p'">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Choose</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="raza2">
          <ion-option value="pastor aleman">Pastor Aleman</ion-option>
          <ion-option value="schnauzer">schnauzer</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</ion-row>
```

So long I haven't reached the ng-if to work and I don't know why. If you could help me figure out why. Thanks

Comment: Hi Can you check if value is set properly in `tipo` or not? By showing value in templete `{{tipo}}`

Comment: Hey @A.J I did it in my template and the value appears once i click in any of these :)

Comment: tried to make it also with ng-hide but doesn't works either

Comment: also you are keeping value `g` as checked on template loading, so does it show g from start? and does ng-if work fine on first load?

Comment: hey, thanks for answer, yes, it seems to be not chosen  (value is not showed) until i press any of them

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, these kind of issues are related to javascript references. instead of
     $scope.tipo, use
     $scope.someNamespace = {
         tipo: ''
     };

then use someNamespace.tipo instead of tipo in html